# What version of IE does Compatibility View use by default?

Tags: browsers, internet-explorer, compatibility

My *understanding* of IE Compatibility Mode/View is that you can specify which version of IE you want to render a domain (or set of domains) in.

But when I go to `Tools >> Compatibility View Settings` it only allows me to add a bunch of sites to be displayed in Compatibility View.

My question is, what version of IE is this Compatibility View using? If I add `example.com` and `blah.net` to Compatibility View, what version of IE will they be displayed in?

Answer (score 4):

You're conflating two seperate functions for two different audiences.

**Developers** can use meta tags to [force IE to render *similarly* to an older version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#DCNeeds):-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

**Users** can click the [compatibility view](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view) button in the browser front end, which forces IE to render *similarly* to it's previous version e.g. IE8 would render as IE7, IE7 as IE6 etc.

I say *similarly* because the forced mode is different under some circumstances to the *actual* old version, one does not precisely emulate the other, and I've seen some bugs which appear to belong to compatibility mode alone!